# WebView topmost and bottommost

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

My app has a sequence of html files that i want to show to the user one by one. When the user is scrolling to the bottom of the page, i want to load the next page and when he is scrolling upwards, i want to load the previous page. For this i need to know when user is scrolling to bottommost (or upmost). So i overrided `onOverScrolled()` and `onScrollChanged()`, one at a time.

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt)
{
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    int height = (int) Math.floor(this.getContentHeight() * this.getScale());  
    int webViewHeight = this.getMeasuredHeight();  
    if(this.getScrollY() + webViewHeight >= height)
    {  
        loadNextPage();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY)
{
    super.onOverScrolled(scrollX, scrollY, clampedX, clampedY);
    if(clampedY)
    {
        if (!(canScrollVertically(SCROLL_DOWN)))
            loadNextPage();
        else if (!(canScrollVertically(SCROLL_UP)))
            loadPrePage();
    }
}
```

Both codes work but the problem is sometimes the code gets called multiple times. Suppose i am in page 1, scrolling to the bottom,
then instead of page 2, page 8 will show up ( the number is different, sometimes i get 2 pages forward, sometimes 5 pages ...)

How can i deal with this?

Comment: Try to do the same with javaScript

Comment: @NickF: what is the different?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this problem you have is because when you scroll until the end the WebView scroll stayed in overscroll mode and when new page is loaded the WebView loads the next page.

Comment: since i can't code in javascript (and this is android platform), do you have any other idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: are you reloading the current webview or adding more webviews to the screen?

Comment: @GregEnnis: the content will be reloaded with new file. but this is not matter, suppose i put this code instead of 'nextPage()' :
'Log.w("myTAG", "the end reached");'
that string printed several times. 
problem is this multiple call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the first line in `loadNextPage` or `loadPrePare`, set a flag indicating the webview is reloading. Do not process any scroll notifications while this flag is set.

When the webview finishes loading, clear the flag. You can get notified that the webview has finished loading by using the `WebViewClient.onPageFinished` method.

Comment: thanks, works fine. i turn the if statement to this: `if(clampedY & reloadFlag)` and set `reloadFlag = true;` in `onPageFinished()`